# How do I select only unique records (based on criteria)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that selects data based on certain criteria, the problem is that some of this data are duplicates. Duplicates are only items with duplicate `CrewCode`, `CrewInvoice` and `Amounts`.

How can I return only unique items based on this criteria?

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex1 as CrewCode, 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex5 as WorkOrder, 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex8 as Amount, 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex6 as BatchName, 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex2 as CrewInvoice
FROM 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16
INNER JOIN 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_4 ON PVDM_DOCS_1_16.DOCINDEX5=PVDM_DOCS_1_4.DOCINDEX1
WHERE
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex3 BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
    AND PVDM_DOCS_1_4.DOCINDEX9 != 'Phone' 
    AND ISNUMERIC(PVDM_DOCS_1_16.DOCINDEX8) = 1
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the table?  Are there any unique keys on the table?  How much do you care about WorkOrder and BatchName?  Additional information like this will help to provide more useful answers.  (Getting "some set of unique results" vs. "the right set of unique results.")

Comment: Maybe you should have a group by for the other fields and sum for the amount and max for invoice (if it's an invoice number).

Comment: I need WorkOrder and BatchName. Basically what I need to select is unique invoices with the smallest batch date (which is the date when they were received). Each record in the table has a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Max on each item to be unique, group by each unique item.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Max(PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex1) as CrewCode, 
    Max(PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex5) as WorkOrder
    -- Removed to be shorter
FROM 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16
INNER JOIN 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_4
ON 
    PVDM_DOCS_1_16.DOCINDEX5=PVDM_DOCS_1_4.DOCINDEX1
WHERE
    -- ...
Group By PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex1, PVDM_DOCS_1_16.docindex5
```

I should add that you may need to change 1 or more of your `where` clauses to a `having` clause.